# How to enable WCF Ria service for ComplexType as reasult from SP?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

As learned from Sliverlight forum, WCF ria Service does not support ComplexType, but EF 4.0 supply complextype for results of stored procedure. 
So if I want to use the results from stored procedure to feed data for datagrid in silverlight client, what's the solution? how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF 4.0 *can* supply complex types for proc results, but it doesn't *have* to. You can map regular entities, as well.

Comment: the result is different from any existing entity. you means that I need to create a new entity to match this result? Or you mean different approach? If so, I'm worry about auto generated process because there are some manual job added. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, you'd create a new entity. At least, until RIA Services gets complex type support, which would hopefully be soon.

Comment: I have created an Entity in edmx to match the result of SP. I can compile it. Then I use it in Ria Services. When compiling ria service project, it gave me the error `No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet`. For this result, I did not need to map it to a real table!

Answer (score 1):

See the following:

http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/ria-services-sending-complex-types-to-the-client/

I tried it; it works. Also, it seems WCF RIA Services SP1 will be released soon, and it supports complex types.